# Vite config started failing on build for shopify app

Tags: reactjs, shopify, vite

The frontend build for my shopify app has all of sudden started to error out. I haven't made code changes since so there is something up with packages or some breaking change.

Running the app locally still works without issue but as soon as I build to production the embedded fails to render:

```
index-d27b9a09.js:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index-d27b9a09.js:79:72236
```

This is due to the require statement being outputted into the index.js bundle but this was not occcuring previously.

[image: require failure]

Below is my vite configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import https from "https";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

if (
  process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === "build" &&
  !process.env.CI &&
  !process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY
) {
  console.warn(
    "\nBuilding the frontend app without an API key. The frontend build will not run without an API key. Set the SHOPIFY_API_KEY environment variable when running the build command.\n"
  );
}

const proxyOptions = {
  target: `http://127.0.0.1:${process.env.BACKEND_PORT}`,
  changeOrigin: false,
  secure: true,
  ws: false,
};

const host = process.env.HOST
  ? process.env.HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, "")
  : "localhost";

let hmrConfig;
if (host === "localhost") {
  hmrConfig = {
    protocol: "ws",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 64999,
    clientPort: 64999,
  };
} else {
  hmrConfig = {
    protocol: "wss",
    host: host,
    port: process.env.FRONTEND_PORT,
    clientPort: 443,
  };
}

export default defineConfig({
  root: dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)),
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    "process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY": JSON.stringify(process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY),
  },
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
  },
  server: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: process.env.FRONTEND_PORT,
    hmr: hmrConfig,
    proxy: {
      "^/(\\?.*)?$": proxyOptions,
      "^/api(/|(\\?.*)?$)": proxyOptions,
      "^/bundle/checkout(\\?.*)?$": proxyOptions,
    },
  },  
});
```

From what I have researched the fix potentially could be to add the commonjs transformations to the vite build to be able to support the require statement versus the import. I am just confused on why this would be necessary now as it was not before and I was importing react without issue. Just want to make sure im going down the right rabbit hole here and would be nice to understand why this is occurring.

Updated, below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "shopify-frontend-template-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.16"
  },
  "stylelint": {
    "extends": "@shopify/stylelint-polaris"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@formatjs/intl-locale": "^3.3.2",
    "@formatjs/intl-localematcher": "^0.4.0",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^5.2.4",
    "@shopify/app-bridge": "^3.7.7",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^3.7.7",
    "@shopify/i18next-shopify": "^0.2.3",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^10.49.1",
    "@shopify/react-form": "^2.5.5",
    "@shopify/react-hooks": "^3.0.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "1.2.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "i18next": "^23.1.0",
    "i18next-resources-to-backend": "^1.1.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.0",
    "react-query": "^3.34.19",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shopify/stylelint-polaris": "^12.0.0",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "stylelint": "^15.6.1",
    "vi-fetch": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: you mentioned some packages added to the package.json, can you share which package you added

Comment: Facing same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77148072/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-shopify-php-react-browser-issue

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77148072/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-shopify-php-react-browser-issue/77156173#77156173

Answer (score -1):

The Shopify internal dev teams have investigated this issue and it appears it was related to [our i18nFormat plugin for the i18next library](https://github.com/Shopify/i18next-shopify). We've shipped a fix to the above plugin to resolve this, so to fix this issue developers should  update `@shopify/i18next-shopify` to `0.2.9`. If anyone is still experiencing this problem after updating please let us know.

Comment: Yeah that's great until they break it next time, a better fix is linked in the duplicate article.